# Como adicionar as checagens do Express-Validator dentro de outro middleware?

Tags: node.js, express.js, middleware, validator

Estou utilizando o Express-Validator para validar os dados que o usuário entra.

```
router.post('/register', [check('email').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Enter an email.'), check('password', 'The password must be at least 6 characters').not().isEmpty()], checkData, registerPostRoute);
```

Porém, eu acho que fica muito poluído colocar todas essas checagens alí, antes do próximo middleware.
Por outro lado, não consigo passar essas checagens para dentro do middleware `checkData` para que o código fique apenas assim:

```
router.post('/register', checkData, registerPostRoute);
```

Não sei se estou fazendo corretamente, mas alguém sabe se é possível passar essas checagens para dentro do middleware `checkData`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim é possível.
Uma maneira que eu faço em meus projetos é organizar os middlewares de validação em um arquivo dedicado apenas para isso.

Segue uma sugestão de organização dos middlewares de validação:

***login.validator.js***

```
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

exports.validationBodyRules = [
    body('login', 'login is required').exists(),
    body('password', 'password is required').exists(),
    body('login', 'login is required').notEmpty(),
    body('password', 'password is required').notEmpty()
];

exports.checkRules = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    next();
};
```

Neste exemplo faço uso da função de validação `body`. No seu caso basta continuar utilizando o `check`.

Também é necessário utilizar a função `validationResult` ele vai servir para levantar as mensagens de erro e parar o encadeamento dos middlewares, para este caso estou lançando o status-code 400 (esse é um detalhe de implementação, mas é possível lançar o seu `status-code` definido na estória disponibilizada para esta funcionalidade).

Depois de criar os middlewares de validação basta utilizar na rota que deseja, da seguinte forma:

***route.js***

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const loginService = require('../controllers/login.controller');
const loginValidator = require('../validators/login.validator');

router.post('/login', loginValidator.validationBodyRules, loginValidator.checkRules, loginService.logEmployee);

module.exports = router;
```

Este é um exemplo de organização que utilizo em meus projetos, que também é a maneira de implementação recomendada pela [documentação do express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/).

Comment: Neste mesmo esquema, como eu faria pra comparar 2 campos de password (pra ver se eles são iguais)? Eu vi várias respostas no StackOverflow e nenhuma funcionou.

Comment: Geralmente eu faço essa verificação no html utilizando javascript, antes de submeter o form de cadastro, um dos itens que eu verifico é a igualdade da confirmação do password.

Comment: Apenas após passar essa validação que o usuário pode fazer o submit do form, aí eu só uso o valor da variável password mesmo (sem fazer nenhum tipo de comparação).